# What InMemoryDbService is for? angular 6

Tags: angular6

Im trying to get more than one object from In Memory Data service and i cant manage to do that, just wondering if it is even possible to get? or i just can have one testing data without possibility to extend it it looks like that:

```
      import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';

export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
    createDb() {
        const groups = [
            {id: 0, name: 'Mr. Nice'},
            {id: 12, name: 'Narco'},
            {id: 13, name: 'Bombasto'},
            {id: 14, name: 'Celeritas'},
            {id: 15, name: 'Magneta'},
            {id: 16, name: 'RubberMan'},
            {id: 17, name: 'Dynama'},
            {id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ'},
            {id: 19, name: 'Magma'},
            {id: 20, name: 'Tornado'},
        ];
        return {groups}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get the whole array from the InMemoryDbService you need to send a http get request to the address: **'api/groups'**.

In case you want only a specific object returned from the list you need to send a http get request to the address: **'api/groups/id'** where id is one of the numbers defined in your groups const.

In case you meant to add another collection to the InMemoryDbService, you can just define a new const array and then add it to the return part of the createDb method like this:

```
const itemList = [
  {id: 1, name: "First item"},
  {id: 2, name: "Second item"},
];

return {
    groups: groups,
    items: itemList
}
```

Note that the endpoints now are: **'api/groups'**, **'api/groups/id'**, **'api/items'** and **'api/items/id'** where id is one of the numbers defined in your const arrays.

You also need to register the **InMemoryWebApiModule** in the imports array of your app.module.ts:

```
imports: [
  InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDbService)
],
```

Comment: Thanks! I just want to do something like this!